# Powershell Function Parameter not working

Tags: function, powershell, csv, parameters, scripting

New to Powershell (and scripting in general). 
This is driving me nuts.

Trying to create a function to script some Admin work in Active Directory and I've fallen at the first hurdle...

```
$groups = import-csv C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Powershell\Scripts\TraineeAdmin\groups.csv
```

The above code works just fine when run in PowerShell

```
Function Trainee-Admin {
  param($groups = import-csv C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Powershell\Scripts\TraineeAdmin\groups.csv)
    $groups
}

Trainee-Admin
```

The same command in the functions parameters doesn't work.
I just get this error instead:

Missing expression after '='.
At C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Powershell\Scripts\TraineeAdmin\TraineeAdmin.p
s1:3 char:14
+     $groups = <<<<  import-csv C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Powershell\Scrip
ts\TraineeAdmin\groups.csv
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (=:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRec
ordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterToken

I'm guessing I'm missing something very simple, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use a param in a function when you hardcode the value? 
 Try like this:

```
Function Trainee-Admin {
  param($groups)
    write-host $groups
}
$groups = import-csv -path "C:\Users\administrator\Desktop\Powershell\Scripts\TraineeAdmin\groups.csv"
Trainee-Admin -groups $groups
```

Comment: Thanks guiwhatsthat,

Comment: No problem, please mark it as an answer when it solved your problem.

Comment: I was using the parameter part of the function to declare variables to use in the function. 
I had forgotten that the parameter part was used to literally create parameters for the function itself to use.
Like I said - total newbie.